# svg to html using linq

Tags: xml, linq

Do you know how to extract a property of the "style" attribute with linq in vb?
ex:   from svg.xml(a typical svg type file)

```
<rect x="20" y="20" width="250" height="250"
 style="fill:blue;stroke:pink;stroke-width:5;"/>
```

The regular attributes are easy to get to: in vb, with linq you would specify @width to extract the xml "width" attribute value - how do we refer to the "fill", "stroke" or "stroke-width" property of the "style" attribute to extract their value? The goal of this is to transform an svg file to html showing rectangles filled with color. This has to be done with linq in visual basic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The content of the `style` attribute is not XML, it's just text (well, CSS actually). So Linq to XML can't help you parsing it. What you could do is extract the content of the attribute to a string (using Linq to XML), and then parse the string manually

```
Dim style As String = ... ' your Linq query
Dim parts As String() = style.Split(New Char() {';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim fillPart = parts.FirstOrDefault(Function(s) s.StartsWith("fill:")
Dim fill As String
If fillPart IsNot Nothing Then
    parts = style.Split(';')
    fill = parts(1)
End If
```

Comment: how do i close or cancel a question?

Comment: You should have a delete button at the bottom of the question. But don't delete this one, since it has an answer...

Comment: Would you know how to re-write the above using the string Replace function? I was thinking of replacing either side of the value I want, ex. "blue" with empty strings using regex.replace with wildcards. Does this make any sense? The required value has to end up as ex. background-color: blue - or whatever value it is.

Comment: I would do it with 2 variables

Comment: I would do it with 2 variables  - 1st I would select whats to the left of the word I want and replace it w/whitespace, then replace everything to the right of what I want and replace with whitespace  -ex. Dim leftstring = mainstring.Replace(" *fill:, " ")      then        -ex. Dim finalstring = leftstring.Rplace(" *; , " ")   ending up with   finalstring = blue or whatever color is left. Another challange is this has to fit in between literals that are defining the html output. - Or can they be class level variables?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do... what's wrong with using Split? Replace doesn't seem like a good option for this kind of task...

Comment: Well I tried your code and get syntax errors trying to add Dim...  within linq <% & vbcode & "background-color:" & vbresult &  %> tags and the person who designed this challenge said he had used string.replace to solve it.

Comment: Now that you know where i need to use your Split code - can you help me figure out if the code will work inside the linq code or if varibles/constants need to be declared at class level

Comment: I might add that this is a complete this code exercise that starts with  Dim svg as XElement.Load("../../test.svg.xml")